# You roll a die $3$ times. What's the probability that the greatest number of pips is exactly $3$?

Tags: probability

> You roll a six sided die $3$ times so there are $3$ number of pips. What's the
>   probability that the greatest number of pips is exactly $3$?

I'm not sure how to solve that correctly.

So a die has six surfaces with integers $1$ to $6$. We want greatest number of pips to be $3$, so we can ignore the surfaces $4,5,6$. Thus we have a probability of $\frac{1}{2}$ to dice $1$ or $2$ or $3$.

To get the probability we are looking for, I would do $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{3}= \frac{1}{8}= 12,5$%

Is it correct like that?

Comment: Excuse me for my ignorance but what is a pip?

Comment: @DenizTunaYalçın A pip is a little dot on the face of a die.  They are the marks that indicate the number that you have thrown.

Comment: @DenizTunaYalçın Sorry my English. By pips I mean the number you diced.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thank you:))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a counting approach. You want to enumerate all three-digit strings using the digits 1, 2, and 3 that contain at least one 3. We could obtain this by counting all three-digit strings that may or may not use a 3 ($3 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 = 27$ of these) and subtracting the three-digit strings that have no 3's ($2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 = 8$ of these). This gives us a total of 19 successes out of $6 \cdot 6 \cdot 6 = 216$ possible throws of the dice, for a probability of
$$
\frac{19}{216} \approx 8.8\%.
$$

Answer (score 2):

You are including cases where the maximum rolled is $2$ or $1$ so you need to deduct these to get only those where the greatest number is exactly $3$

Comment: $$\left(\frac{1}{2 \cdot 2}\right)^3$$ ?

Comment: @cnmesr it is simpler than that